# Auto stop groovy bot in discord

Tags: discord, chatbot

I use groovy bot in my discord for music. recently i have seen people spamming and some people's turn never coming.

How can i limit the song to 90 seconds per user so that song stops automatically after the time?

either i add a command to groovy music or add a separate bot so that it automatically sends stop command after 90 seconds.

i tried adding a auto reply bot but it seems to not work properly.
i can also switch to a better bot if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Octave](https://top.gg/bot/octave), another music bot has an option to set the maximum song length

The settings command as of now is `_settings`